# How is child action called? by parent view or by user action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In Asp.NET MVC project I want to know how is child action called: by parent view with Render.Action or Html.Action or by user action with clicking a link? How can I know that?

Comment: A `[ChildActionOnly]` method can only be called by `@Html.Action(...)` or `@{ Html.RenderAction(...); }` (it cannot be called by user interaction)

Comment: I know it. Thanks. But this action could be called both html.action, html.renderaction and by user action.

Comment: Read the comment carefully - a [ChildActionOnly] method **cannot** be called by user interaction

Comment: But my action could be invoked both by user action and by parent view. So I can not use ChildActionOnly attribute in this case. And in the action I want to know how is this action called?